# Does MS Access automatically write back records to a database?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010

We have a database in SQL Server 2008r2, and with have two user interfaces:

- A custom interface, written in C#/.NET 4.0
- An Access database, which has "linked tabled" to some tables in the SQL Server database

Now we had this incident:

1. A user was deleting some records with the custom interface, and was then creating some reports out of the database. The delete transacion was committed for sure (there are some jobs involved in the report creation, which are running in different processes, so the delete was commmitted for sure)
2. During step 1, the MS Access interface was always open at the same computer, showing the table in the status before the delete.  (Access does not do an automatic refresh by default). And then, the same user added some records into the table with the MS Access interface.

Finally, after some days, we found that the records deleted in Step 1) had been restored!

We have tracked back the case in detail, have also spoken with the database admins, and our only possible explanation is that the MS Access interface has possibly written back the records. Could this really happen?

Answer (score 1):

When using an Access form to edit data, then no save is required, and the save occurs when you close the form, move to another record, or have code that explicit forces the save of data.

In your case it seems that the delete command was not committed, or was not executed. If access ADDED the records again, do you have an auto number PK? (those numbers would CHANGE). I assume you have some PK column here and if Access actually did re-add and re-write out those rows, then the PK keys if autonumber type would be DIFFERENT.

However, to answer your question in your context?

If the records were deleted, then no Access would not automatically re-create those rows of data, and EVEN if access was to attempt to update those rows, you clearly stated they did not exist and thus EVEN IF Access was attempting to automatic write data back to a row on SQL server, this would NOT be possible since the rows DO NOT exist and any commands by Access to update those rows would FAIL. Access would NOT be issuing INSERT commands, but would be attempting UPDATE commands.

So EVEN if Access did automatic write back such records (which it does not unless they are changed by Access) the UPDATE command(s) would fail because you cannot update rows of data that don’t exist anymore.

So the process of INSERTING records vs that of UPDATING EXISTING records is a SIGNIFICANTLY DIFFERENT PROCESS, and if those rows were deleted, Access would not know this, and would be executing UPDATE commands, and not INSERT commands. As such the attempts by Access to UPDATE such rows would fail since they no longer exist. And for SURE Access does not out of the blue re-execute SQL insert commands for rows that Access already knows and assumes to exist.